# Remove all combination of set at the end of string REGEX

Tags: python, string, filter, combinations

I want to write a REGEX that removes all combination of a group of characters from the end of strings. For instance removes "k", "t", "a", "u" and all of their combinations from the end of the string:

**Input:**

```
["Rajakatu","Lapinlahdenktau","Nurmenkaut","Linnakoskenkuat"]
```

**Output**:

```
["Raja","Lapinlahden","Nurmen","Linnakosken"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this `[ktau]{4}\b`?
https://regex101.com/r/BVwTcs/1

This will match at the end of a word for those character combinations.
For example, k, followed by u, followed by a, followed by t.

This can also match `aaaa` so take that into account.
It will match any 4 combinations of the characters at the end of the word.

Answer (score 0):

the below is my approach to it. Please try it:

```
from itertools import permutations

mystr = [["Rajakatu","Lapinlahdenktau","Nurmenkaut","Linnakoskenkuat"]]

#to get the last four letters of whose permutations you need
x = mystr[0][0]
exclude= x[-4:]

#get the permutations
perms = [''.join(p) for p in permutations(exclude)]
perms

#remove the last for letters of the string if it lies in the perms
for i in range(4):
    curr = mystr[0][i]
    last4 = curr[-4:]
    
    if(last4 in perms):
        mystr[0][i]=curr[:-4]
    
print(mystr)
```

OUTPUT: [['Raja', 'Lapinlahden', 'Nurmen', 'Linnakosken']]